# pam_tty_audit and non privileged users

Tags: centos, pam, tty, auditd

I'm working on a cents 6.3 box and am trying to log all commands executed from a bash shell and came across pam_tty_audit. I've added the appropriate line to my `/etc/pam.d/system-auth file`:

```
session     required      pam_tty_audit.so enable=*
```

The problem is that it does not appear to capture commands unless a user is root. For example, if i ssh in as root it logs everything to the audit log, but if I ssh as a regular user it does not start logging anything until after I have su to root.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

This could be due to a built in protection from the auditing system. Here is a relevant quote from somebody debugging your same situation. It appears as though non-root users are prevented from sending the USER_TTY records. Instead commands will be written out either when bash exits or the collection buffer fills up.

You *should* be able to find the information you're looking for after the user logs out.